# Activex control for web print

Tags: printing, activex

I would like to find  an Internet Explorer ActiveX control that will allow me to print a web page or part of web page  to a specific printer without a dialog box.

Is there any activex plugin to achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just ask how to print a page without a dialog box? Why limit solutions to only ActiveX? If someone has an ActiveX answer, that's great, but other answers would be OK, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [ScriptX](http://scriptx.meadroid.com). The free version lets you set some basic parameters, see the example below.

Example:

```
<!-- MeadCo ScriptX -->
<object id=factory style="display:none"
  classid="clsid:1663ed61-23eb-11d2-b92f-008048fdd814"
  codebase="http://[your path here]/smsx.cab#Version=7.0.0.8 ">
</object>


<script>
  function printWindow() {
    factory.printing.header = "This is MeadCo";
    factory.printing.footer = "Printing by ScriptX";
    factory.printing.portrait = false;
    factory.printing.leftMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.topMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.rightMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.bottomMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.Print(false);
  }
</script>
```